# Testing for Application level permission on Marshmallow when target API is less than Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an application that has a targetSDKversion of 21 (can't move up above 21 yet).

It uses Location services but I've been able to test to make sure the system level location permission is enabled but on a device with 6.0 installed, you can turn off the application level location permissions.  I haven't been able to determine if this level of permissions has been enabled or not.

I'm currently calling the following:

```
locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(activity.getContentResolver(),
    Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
returnVal = (locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);
```

Which returns a true value since the locationMode is 3 (that it's been enabled) even though the location at application level has been disabled.

A lot of the references I've been finding on line all use API calls that are not available in API 21 (which we just can't go to yet.)

Can anyone give me something that I can check on newer devices to see if the application level permissions are enabled or not but still be able to do this test with a targetSDKVersion of 21.  I will be testing that the Build.VERSION is >= 23 before doing this test.  Or is this even possible?

Comment: I *think* that [`PermissionChecker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/PermissionChecker.html) will cover this scenario. That being said, I'd focus less on this and more on making the code changes necessary for you to be able to raise your `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: The .content.PermissionChecker can't be resolved in my environment.  I'm assuming that it's not available until targetedSDKVersion is 22 or 23?  I would love to move up to a newer API but this is a bank application and we can't move it up until they get approval and funding to do so since it's some work to remove older libraries that it's currently using that fail on API 23.

Comment: `PermissionChecker` is part of the Android Support libraries (e.g., `support-v4`).

Comment: I can see it in the Android Developers site that it should be there but when I try to do an import of android.support.v4.content.PermissionChecker it cannot find PermissionChecker.  And even if I leave off the PermissionChecker in the import using a '*'. It still can't find PermissionChecker.

I thought the Android Developers site used to list what versions of SDK/API was needed for different libraries but I don't see anything for these unless that means it should be there, but I sure can't find it unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: What version of the support libraries are you using? IOW, what is the version number behind `com.google.android:support-v4` or other `com.google.android` artifacts in your dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to see if an application level permission is on or off.  It checks based on API level as well so it is safe to use on all devices.

```
boolean hasApplicationLevelLocationPermission(Context context) {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

Comment: I cannot get the ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission() to work.  It gets error that it can't resolve it.  I've included the import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.

Comment: Have you added the v4 support library as a Gradle dependency?

Comment: I've got: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3' in my Gradle.

Comment: And just for info to go with our targetSDKversion of 21, it has the following: buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"   compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:21"

Comment: The application has things like the ActionBarSherlock and the Apache http client which both don't work in SDK 23.  So we have to wait for funding approval before we can remove these and redo the http client and work out issue differences when pulling out the ActionBarSherlock.